# Category tree in "Manage Categories" page - not showing subcategories

Tags: category-tree

In my magento's "**Manage Categories**" page, clicking the + sign for a particular category, makes the plus sign disappears and no subcategories are displayed.

If I access category tree, by selecting **Catalog > Manage Products > (select product) > Categories tab**, the category tree **works ok**.

1) There are no javascript errors on Manage Categories page
2) I checked the catalog_category_entity table. The category's path, level and children_count seem correct to me:

- entity_id: 7
- parent_id: 2
- path: 1/2/7
- position: 1
- level: 2
- children_count: 22252

Any suggestions about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your javascript libraries are not being served compressed and merged in admin. You can set the default admin view to not be merged/minified and then, at the store level, set it to be merged/minified. In this way, in admin, every js/css file is served separately rather than in one badly merged bundle.

Also check that you haven't got anything like Google pagespeed running. That can overly merge the javascripts and it is usually the category tree browser that is first to go.

Try the above change with cache off.

Comment: After spending hours o this issue, I dinally found that this was some kind of server issue, and it was solved after website's server was reset by hosting company.... Thank you for your answer anyway:)